# Is use of ols (python statsmodel) correct for longitudinal data and multiple dependent variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, statsmodels, patsy

I am still a noob when it comes to statistics. 
I am using Python Package Statsmodel, with the patsy functionality.

My pandas dataframe looks as such:

```
index         sed   label           c_g  lvl1 lvl2
0             5.0   SP_A            c    b    c
1            10.0   SP_B            g    b    c
2             0.0   SP_C            c    b    c
3           -10.0   SP_H            c    b    c
4             0.0   SP_J            g    b    c
5           -20.0   SP_K            g    b    c
6            30.0   SP_W            g    a    a
7            40.0   SP_X            g    a    a
8           -10.0   SP_Y            c    a    a
9            45.0  SP_BB            g    a    a
10           45.0  SP_CC            g    a    a
11           10.0   SP_A            c    b    c
12           10.0   SP_B            g    b    c
13           10.0   SP_C            c    b    c
14            6.0   SP_D            g    b    c
15           10.0   SP_E            c    b    c
16           29.0   SP_F            c    b    c
17            3.0   SP_G            g    b    c
18           23.0   SP_H            c    b    c
19           34.0   SP_J            g    b    c
```

**Dependent variable:** Sedimentation (longitudinal data)

**Independent variables**: Label (categorical), control_grid (categorical), lvl1(categorical) , lvl2 (categorical).

I am interested in two things.

Which Independent variables have significant effect on Dependent variable?

Which Independent variables have significant interaction?

After having searched and read multiple documents, I do this as such:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.read_csv('some.csv')
model = smf.ols(formula = 'sedimentation ~ lvl1*lvl2',data=df)
results = model.fit()
results.summary()
```

With results showing:

```
    OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:          sedimentation   R-squared:                       0.129
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.124
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     24.91
Date:                Tue, 17 Jul 2018   Prob (F-statistic):           4.80e-15
Time:                        11:15:28   Log-Likelihood:                -2353.6
No. Observations:                 510   AIC:                             4715.
Df Residuals:                     506   BIC:                             4732.
Df Model:                           3                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
=======================================================================================
                          coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept               6.9871      1.611      4.338      0.000       3.823      10.151
lvl1[T.b]              -3.7990      1.173     -3.239      0.001      -6.103      -1.495
lvl1[T.d]              -3.5124      1.400     -2.509      0.012      -6.263      -0.762
lvl2[T.b]              -8.9427      1.155     -7.744      0.000     -11.212      -6.674
lvl2[T.c]               5.1436      0.899      5.722      0.000       3.377       6.910
lvl2[T.f]              -3.5124      1.400     -2.509      0.012      -6.263      -0.762
lvl1[T.b]:lvl2[T.b]    -8.9427      1.155     -7.744      0.000     -11.212      -6.674
lvl1[T.d]:lvl2[T.b]          0          0        nan        nan           0           0
lvl1[T.b]:lvl2[T.c]     5.1436      0.899      5.722      0.000       3.377       6.910
lvl1[T.d]:lvl2[T.c]          0          0        nan        nan           0           0
lvl1[T.b]:lvl2[T.f]          0          0        nan        nan           0           0
lvl1[T.d]:lvl2[T.f]    -3.5124      1.400     -2.509      0.012      -6.263      -0.762
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       13.069   Durbin-Watson:                   1.118
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.001   Jarque-Bera (JB):               18.495
Skew:                          -0.224   Prob(JB):                     9.63e-05
Kurtosis:                       3.818   Cond. No.                          inf
==============================================================================
```

**Am I using the correct model in Python to get my desired results?**

I think I am, but I would like to verify. The way I read the table is that the categorical variables lvl1 and lvl2 have a significant effect on the dependent variable AND show significant interaction (for some of the variables). However, I don't understand why not all of my variables are showing...as you see in my data, lvl1 column also contains "a" but this variable is not shown in the results summary.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert and I fear I can't tell you what is the correct test to apply to longitudinal data, but I think that the numbers you got can't really be trusted that much.

First, the easy part of the answer, regarding your "why not all of my variables are showing": for example, in lvl1, "a" is not showing because you have to fix a "base" value of some kind. So you should read every entry as "effect of having 'b' instead of 'a'" and "effect of having 'd' instead of 'a'", etc.. In more mathematical terms, if you have a categorical variable that takes three values (a,b,d here), then when you implicitly one-hot encode them you'll get three dimensions that always have values 0 or 1, and the sum of which is always 1. This means that your final `A` matrix in the regression `y = A.x + b` will always be degenerate, and you have to delete one column to have a chance of it not being so (thus giving any interpretability at all to the regression coefficients).

Concerning why I think the numbers you got cannot be trusted: among the various hypothesis of the linear regression is independence of the consecutive observations (rows). In the case of longitudinal data, this is exactly what clearly fails. Pushing the example to the limit, if you observe a bunch of people (e.g. 11 as in your set) every second for 1 day, you'll get a huge data frame of nearly 1M rows, and every single person will have virtually the same data repeated over and over again. In this setting, any spurious correlation between the independent and dependent variable will be seen by your model as hugely significant (to him, you've run 86400 independent tests and they all exactly confirmed the same conclusion!), while of course this is not the case.

Summing up, I can't say for sure that the regression coefficients you get are not the best guess you can hope for, but certainly the t statistic, the p-value and everything else that looks like statistic there doesn't make much sense.

Comment: thanks! 
Could you be a bit more specific as to why you think the t-statstic and p-values don't make much sense? If you are referring to the nan values, it is because of the some of those combinations of parameters never occur (i.e. lvl1 : lvl2d)

Comment: also, would you recommend maybe using this model: http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/mixed_linear.html

Comment: The reason why I think p values are invalid is what I wrote in the answer, mathematically being "hugely significant" roughly translates "having a tiny p value", so the p values you found are probably smaller than they should. Having nans, I think, is a consequence of a degenerate regression, probably because some product variables are always 0 (from your answer, I think, you never have lvl 1 equal to d and lvl 2 equal to b, for example). This is also not great but less problematic

Comment: Concerning the other package, I don't know it at all, so I can't comment much, but at least it claims to be good for longitudinal data, so yes it looks more promising! But please don't take this as an educated answer :-)